# Get links from external site with php

Tags: php, angularjs, dom, foreach

I'm using this little fancy script to grab the links from an external site:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.iamjonas.de/');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
{
  echo $node->nodeValue.': '.$node->getAttribute("href")."\n";
}

?>
```

The script works quite fine. But if I'm trying to get the links from https://cannasos.com/ the output is empty. I think the problem is that the content is generated dynamically. Is there a workaround for it? What do you think?

Comment: So do you believe it is empty because the time you load the html file's content is not fully loaded? Have you tried to use the "for each" after some seconds?

Comment: If they make an ajax request to get the content, you can try loading the same file. However, I wouldn't be surprised if that didn't work, they can - for example - use a session to avoid visitors loading these pages like that.

Comment: It is better to use headless browser for such things. Try this one http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/